# Failed To Save Relationship Data In jQuery AJAX 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable, relationship

I am trying to save data without relationship and success, but when I try to save data with one to many relationship, it's failed with 500 (Internal Server Error).

**Table**
[image]

**Product Model**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}

/** 
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'id', 'name', 'product_code', 'product_photo'
];
```

**Category Model**

```
public function product() // parent 
{
    // one job only belongs to one type of job
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}

/** 
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'id', 'name'
];
```

**Controller**

```
// Save data to table product
    $product = new \App\Product;
    $product->name = $request->get('name');
    $product->product_code = $request->get('code');

    $productCode = \App\Product::where('product_code', '=', $request->get('code'))->first();

    if ($productCode === null) {
        $product->save();

        // Save relationship data between product and categories
        $getCategories = $request->get('categories');
        $productId = DB::table('products')->select('id')->where('product_code', $request->get('code'))->get();
        $theProduct = \App\Product::withTrashed()->findOrFail($productId);
        $theProduct->category()->attach($getCategories);

    }
    

    return response()->json(['success' => 'Product added successfully']);
```

**View**

```
<select style="width:100%;" placeholder="Select Categories" name="categories[]" multiple
                            id="categories"
                            class="categories form-control {{ $errors->first('categories') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}"></select>

$('#saveBtnForCreate').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('products.store') }}",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                code: $('#code').val(),
                categories: $('#categories').val(),
            },
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.errors) {
                    $('.alert-danger').html(
                        'An error in your input! Make sure the product code is unique'
                    );
                    $.each(result.errors, function(key, value) {
                        $('.alert-danger').show();
                        $('.alert-danger').append('<strong><li>' + value +
                            '</li></strong>');
                    });
                } else {
                    $('.alert-danger').hide();
                    $('.alert-success').show();
                    $('.datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    setInterval(function() {
                        $('.alert-success').hide();
                        location.reload();
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

You know, when I am trying to save data without relationship (product name & product code) its success. But when I am trying to save relationship data between product and categories, it's failed with 500 (Internal Server Error). Also, I couldn't use `dd()` for debug the query. Any solution about it?

Comment: Take a look at the server/laravel log. Use your browser's DevTools/Network tab to see any requests/responses

Comment: On network tab, I don't see anything. I just see 500 (Internal Server Error) in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. Since you need to insert new data with relationship in one time, you need to use `insertGetId` method. This method will retrieve the id of last inserted data, so you can use the Id to perform relationship.

```
$productName = $request->get('name');
    $productCode = $request->get('code');
        $productId = DB::table('products')->insertGetId(
            [
                'name' => $productName,
                'product_code' => $productCode
            ]
        );

        // Save relationship data between product and categories
        $categoryId = $request->get('categories');
        $theProductId = \App\Product::withTrashed()->findOrFail($productId);
        $theProductId->category()->attach($categoryId);
```